# In woocommerce subscription plugin How can we do if customer downgrade their subscription then the wordpess take order status to on hold

Tags: wordpress, subscription

In woocommerce subscription plugin How can we do if customer downgrade their subscription then the wordpess should take request and process but order should be on hold.

```html
 // Check if the product is an upgrade or downgrade

function is_downgrade( $new_product_id, $current_product ) {
return wc_get_product( $new_product_id )->get_price() < $current_product->get_price();
}

// Prevent Downgrading unless 3 months have passed
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_switch_is_identical_product', function( $is_identical_product, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $subscription, $item ) {
// Check if the switch is a downgrade
if ( is_downgrade( $product_id, $item->get_product() ) ) {
    // Get the start date of the subscription and calculate 3 months later
    $start_date = $subscription->get_date( 'start' );
    $three_months_later = strtotime( '+3 months', strtotime( $start_date ) );

    // Check if the current date is less than 3 months after the start date
    if ( current_time( 'timestamp' ) < $three_months_later ) {
        // Put the subscription on hold
        $subscription->update_status( 'on-hold' );

        // Add a custom notice
        wc_add_notice( 'Your downgrade request has been received. Your subscription is now on hold.', 'notice' );

        return true; // Prevent further processing
    }
}

return $is_identical_product;
}, 10, 6 );

// Remove Subscription update button for specific products
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', function( $item_id, $item, $subscription ) {
if ( in_array( $item->get_product()->get_id(), [ 204361 ] ) ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', [ 'WC_Subscriptions_Switcher', 'print_switch_link' ] );
}
}, 10, 3 );
```